# "On peut faire ce qu'on peut faire" vs. "On fait ce que l'on peut faire"

Tags: syntaxe

A French native speaker just told me that

> One must do what one must do

can't be translated into French as

> On peut faire ce qu'on peut faire

because the correct way to say that is

> On fait ce que l'on peut faire.

But

> On fait ce que l'on peut faire

actually means

> One does what one must do.

Is there any explanation why my translation might not be correct?

Comment: Besides the *pouvoir/devoir* confusion m.raynal addresses, I don't think there's anything illogical about *On doit faire ce qu'on doit faire*, though it's a little wordy and sounds to me like a calque of English.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, '**On fait ce que l'on peut faire**' means 'One does what one can do'.

And also, the way people say it generally is : '**On fait ce que l'on peut**'.

Or more often : '**On fait ce que l'on peut avec ce que l'on a**', which means literally 'One does what one can do with what one has'.